# Using Multiple Decorators in urls.py in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have an admin mixin that I'm using to prevent caching and make sure users are logged in by overriding dispatch(). It's being used in my class-based views.

```
# mixins.py
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

class AdminPageMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AdminPageMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

# views.py
class SomeAdminView(AdminPageMixin, ListView):
```

I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to run unit tests against SomeAdminView. Yes, I know I can use django's test client to login, but I'm trying to stay away from writing functional tests. I'd like, instead, to wrap AdminPageMixin functionality into a single decorator and call that decorator in urls.py, like so:

```
url(r'^myurl/$', decorator_wrapper(SomeAdminView.as_view()), name='some-admin-view'),
```

Alternatively, I could do this:

```
url(r'^myurl/$', never_cache(staff_member_required(SomeAdminView.as_view())), name='some-admin-view'),
```

but if I wanted to add a third or forth decorator, I'd be updating a lot of lines in urls.py and repeating a lot of code.

Any ideas how to create this decorator wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite against the spirit of the CBVs to use decorators in the URLconfs. Instead, use mixins to add the functionality directly to the `dispatch` method of the view class.

Comment: How do you go about writing tests of those views without having to call a client?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a client" -- open a browser session? Well, if you need to test a views output there is no other way; but I guess you actually want to test individual methods, such as `get_context_data` or `get_object`, which is easily done with unit tests.

Comment: Is there a better way than this? http://tech.novapost.fr/django-unit-test-your-views-en.html You make it sound trivial.

Comment: Better in what sense? You see, unlike function-based views, which are, well, a single function each, CBVs encapsulate their logic into several methods. So instead of just testing the whole view you really need to test individual methods such as `get_context_data`, but only if you have overridden them in your code; otherwise it's already covered by Django's tests. Actually, the link you've given already includes a great overview of CBV testing -- scroll down to the subtitle "Testing class-based views".

Comment: That's my point. Having to go through the process of "Mimic as_view()" etc. isn't trivial or documented at all, that I'm aware of, by Django. Finding something that succinct took me while.

Comment: Well I guess it's an issue of personal preferences; I find this quite trivial, providing you switch the mindset from functions to objects. While both share the same name of "views", you must be aware that CBVs and FBVs are very different beasts, and should naturally be treated differently. The main point is that you always test a single unit of code (hence the name "unit tests"); with FBVs the unit is the whole view, while with CBVs the units are individual methods, and that is what you test. After all, FBVs are perfectly valid and there is no reason to switch to CBVs if they fit your needs.

Comment: Berislav Lopac is right on this one. Using the methods defined at tech.novapost.fr/django-unit-test-your-views-en.html you're able to test the methods of CBV's, specifically, for my situation, get_success_url.